# What should I do before installing anaconda?

Tags: apt, python, python3

I have been running ubuntu 17.04 since it has been out and have used python3 extensively. Recently I learned about anaconda and want to install it on my computer so I can use jupyter with python 3. Which packages should I uninstall before switching over to anaconda so that the installation will go smoothly? Here is a list of a few packages I've installed which I think may be relevant:

- pip and pip3
- python3
- python3-numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anaconda, by definition, servers as a sandbox that permits you to install packages into strictly defined environments. As long as you're working within one of those environments (running the `activate` command), your environment will see only those packages that you've installed into it. So, to answer your question, what you've installed previously shouldn't matter: Anaconda will only "see" those packages installed into the currently-activated environment.

Some good Anaconda resource reading worth following-up with: [Linux installation](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux.html), and [Managing Environments](https://docs.continuum.io/docs_oss/conda/using/envs#managing-environments).

BTW, we just completed a Python-based project (using TeX of all things), and Anaconda was a great solution for our team, as we could pretty much guarantee consistent, repeatable environments across team members, regardless of base OS.